# I am trying to write a selenium test case in jave for loging to a homepage..But my homepage is not loading..how to do it?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is the outer HTML code for my Login button..
i wrote the following code

```java
WebElement loginButton = driver.findElement(By.id("Login"));
loginButton.click();

System.out.println("button is clicked");
```

I am getting the output as
button is clicked
but i can not see the home page.
i tried to get current url but it is still showing login page..
please help..

i want to see the home page but i am still under login page..not able to understand the reason

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code appears to be correct and is functioning well for me. You might want to consider waiting for the page to fully load using the following code:

```java
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.urlMatches("expected_home_page_url"));
```

If it still doesn't work, the issue might not be with the HTML code. Please ensure that only one button has the "Login" id.

Additionally, could you please provide information about the frontend framework or technology you are using? This could help in further troubleshooting.